# Consume WCF Webservice with angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, wcf

I'm implementing a server with WCF and trying to reach its rest services using a client developed with Angular.

Here is the service :

```
 public interface IConnexion

{

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Connexion/{login}/{mdp}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Utilisateur Connexion(string login, string mdp);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Deconnexion/{id_user}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void Deconnexion(string id_user);
```

}

And my function trying to reach the service :

```
 app.service('serverConnexionServices', function(userService, serverConfigService) {

        this.Connexion = function(login, pass)
        {
            var uri = this.getServerUri() + "Connexion/"+login+"/"+CryptoJS.MD5(pass);

            var promises = $http.get(uri)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            return data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            return "";
        });

return promises;
        };
    });
```

my form's controller:

```
 app.directive('loginContent', function(userService, serverConnexionServices){
                return{
                    restrict : 'E',
                    templateUrl : "includes/home/login-content.html",
                    controllerAs: "loginController",
                    controller: function($scope, userService, serverConnexionServices) {

                    var IsSubmitEnabled = true;
                    this.errors = "";

                    this.validateLogin = function(user) { // Calling the service
                        this.IsSubmitEnabled = false; // To avoid more than one click while checking on the server
                        var retour = serverConnexionServices.TryConnection(user).then(function(promise) {
                        alert('promise:'+retour);
                        if(promise.length > 0)
                        { // There is an error so we show a message to the user
                            this.promise= retour;
                        }
                            this.IsSubmitEnabled = true;
                            user = {};
    });
                        };

                        }
                    }
            });
```

But when I try to open my client the alert box  appears before the breakpoint is raised in Visual Studio (I put the breakpoint on the first line of my "Connexion" function. So it means the server has not answered yet to the request but the $http.get() has already sent its answer. So the result object doesn't contain what the server is sending. According to Angular's documentation, the response will be sent asynchronously. But How can I force my request to wait the answer ?

My controller now gets the answer from the server but it doesn't update the view, and if I try to call manually $scope.$apply() I get the error "$digest already in progress". How can I force my view to refresh itself ? (I noticed that if I put this.errors = "aaa"; once the "then" is closed, my view is refreshed and whos "aaa", I've also checked that errors.length > 0 with an alert message)

My view :

```
<div ng-show="loginController.errors.length > 0" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>{{loginController.errors}}</div>
```

**EDIT**: I can now reach my breakpoint in the implementation of `Connexion` in Visual Studio but still the answer from the server is not what is expected

**EDIT2** : I've added my controller which needs the refresh.

**EDIT3** : Ok, I updated my code, I needed to put a "then" function on my controller's call and my controller now get the answer. However my view doesn't update itself on errors. It should set the div visibility to true but the async call seems to block it. I've tried to use apply() and digest() without success. Could you help me on this ?

Comment: Your code looks more like jQuery than like AngularJS. In AngularJS you can use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to make AJAX call.

Comment: Ok... I followed another tutorial, it seems better (I can now reach my breakpoint in the implementation of "COnnexion" in Visual Studio but still the answer from the server is not what is expected.

Comment: You are probably moving in the right direction and the current problems could be scope related. In my opinion client side code provided here doesn't represent all the relevant parts. Can you make working plunk or jsfiddle or at least point us to URL where your development code can be seen in action?

Comment: Some general advises when trying to consume a moody service: First use sth like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to get your service call working. Then try to do it in angular/jQuery whatever. All you have to do in the end is to compare the actual communication on the wire by using the network tab in the dev tools of your browser (F12). I'm not entirely sure on this but I could imagine that WCF is not that simple to consume. Maybe you're missing some headers or something like that.

Comment: Thank you ! just needed to put $scope.promise and my service is working fine and my UI refreshing !